# Socket.io with client on Firebase Hosting and Server on Heroku

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, heroku, socket.io

I've created an app that uses Angular for the front-end and node.js for the backend. I'm hosting the front-end on Firebase Hosting and the server on Heroku (because I read that Firebase Functions doesn't support socket.io).

In my `socket.service.ts` file, I connect to the socket using `this.socket = io(environment.socket_url);` (`socket_url` is `http://localhost:3000/` for the development environment and `https://PROJECT_NAME_HERE.herokuapp.com:3000` for production).

The socket connection in my `server.ts` file is:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const server = new http.Server(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: socketUrl,
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
});
```

where socketUrl is `http://localhost:4200` when in development  and `https://PROJECT_NAME_HERE.web.app/` in production.

This setup works in development, but doesn't work in production. How do I get this to work?

EDIT:
This is the error I get:
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://PROJECT_NAME_HERE.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NPu1t39' from origin 'https://PROJECT_NAME_HERE.web.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://PROJECT_NAME_HERE.web.app/' that is not equal to the supplied origin.`

I am also using `app.use(cors({origin: true}));`

Comment: "_but doesn't work in production_" === needs debugging details. "Doesn't work" is not reproducible nor resolvable.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thanks for pointing that out. I edited my question with the error I'm getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trouble isolation steps:

1. Replace `origin` in the CORS configuration with `*` and see if you receive the exact same error.

```
    cors: {
        origin: "*",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
```

2. Explicitly set the origin of the CORS config to the Angular app URL and see if you get the same error:

```
    cors: {
        origin: "https://PROJECT_NAME_HERE.web.app",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
```

If either of these produce the exact same error, you've missed a configuration parameter (probably `credentials`). You'll need to determine which parameter you'll need to add from [here](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#configuration-options).

Otherwise, you've not included enough details about additional or custom headers, pre-flight requirements, authentication (credentials/cookies), etc.

Comment: setting the origin to ```*``` worked! Thank you so much! Is it ok to leave it like that?

Comment: Not really safe to leave it that way, but that certainly tells us what the problem is. Did you try #2? did that work?